# How to launch an HTML page using Rest services from another server

Tags: html, rest, web-services, web-applications, jersey

I have a different set of applications, each having their own war files and they could be deployed in different servers.

Assuming that all application sets may need to interact with each other I am trying to develop them as web services. It may happen that an application 'A' installed on server 'X' needs to launch an application 'B' but B's resources like HTML and js are not present on the server where A is installed.

How can we do this? I have come across a few sites where Viewable is used but then it needs the JSPs to be in the same instance. What if I want to achieve this when the calling application doesn't have HTMLs or JSPs with it.

I hope I have been able to put up my question properly. Thanks for any inputs.

Comment: Use a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

As Pesskillet says, you can use a redirection to resource of server B.
If that resource is an HTML view, **you don't need to worry about the loading of static files (CSS, JS, Images etc.)** that are bound to the HTML view. Because the browser of the user will load it **automatically** as soon as it will get the HTML document.

Comment: Thanks both of you.